# How to get all matches using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i need to get all matches in a given word using regex(i.e., all combinations)

Content:

> ABC

From this i need to get AB and BC when i give some pattern like [A-Z][A-Z].
Now it is giving only "AB" as matched pattern.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have completely misunderstood what Regex is for.. You appear to want a permutation algorithm.. not Regex.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead apparently some regex flavors(.net) support it..:)

Comment: @Anirudh Apparently I completely misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead so that you don't consume the matches:

```
(?=([A-Z]{2}))
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/wDLg3L).

Comment: it is working fine for me. @Jerry Do you think any issues will come if we use this?

Comment: @kumar As as see it right now, not really, but it's safer to assume that it will depend on certain situations. Sometimes, some modifications might be required for certain specific input.

Comment: @Jerry In your code it is given match.Groups(1) why it is second item in group collection.Is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0;
List<Match> matches = new List<Match>();
while(i < input.Length){
  Match m = Regex.Match(input.Substring(i),"[A-Z]{2}");
  if(m.Success){
    matches.Add(m);
    i += m.Index+1;
  }else break;
}
```

You can also implement it to support `lazy` matching like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Match> Matches(string input, string pattern) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < input.Length){
            Match m = Regex.Match(input.Substring(i), "[A-Z]{2}");
            if (m.Success) {
                yield return m;
                i += m.Index + 1;
            }
            else yield break;
        }
}
//Use it
var matches = Matches(input, "[A-Z]{2}");
```

Comment: as usual, here for the save...

Answer (score 1):

.NET supports capture groups in lookarounds

```
var result=Regex.Matches(input,"(?=(..))")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int i = 0;
List<Match> matches = new List<Match>();
while(i < input.Length){
  Match m = Regex.Match(input,"[A-Z][Z-A]");
  if(m.Success){
    matches.Add(i++);
    i = m.Index ++ 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code so that others can learn.